# Using a class library variable in an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following object in a class library:

```
namespace ID.CentralisedObjects
{
    public class Details
    {
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in the aspx page in my website project (which has a reference to the class library), I am trying to print out the `ContactName` by using code along the lines of

```
<div><%= ID.CentralisedObjects.Details.ContactName %></div>
```

However, it is thinking that the `ID` at the start of this is `Page.ID` so it isn't finding my object properly.  How do I make it look for the class library `ID`?

Comment: You can only print out the value of an property on an instance, not on the type itself like this.

Comment: Maybe you should make your property static?

Comment: It's actually part of a session object so I'm just trying to print the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standard naming of namespace has enough influence on your application, changing it according to the `naming namespaces guidelines` will solve your problem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Decided this was the easiest thing to do, changed the ID to the full name and recompiled, seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 1):

For the namespace conflict: use a qualifier

```
using DrawCharts IDS = ID;

IDS.CentralisedObjects.Details.ContactName
```

The other mentioned problems are unresolved by this solution.

Comment: can you put `using`s in aspx pages?